# Troubleshooting CSS border on Divs

Tags: html, css, border, stylesheet

I am currently building a grid layout web page [as you can see here in this livelink](http://www.mildenhire.com/Website/copyiframe.html). However I can not work out why the border is not showing up on my 'special offer' square and on my 'portfolio' square. I have tried everything! It is obviously a CSS issue but it works on every other square apart from these two. Could somebody please take a look at the livelink above and view the source code to try to work out why the border isn't working.

***HTML OF ONE OF THE DIVS EFFECTED***

```
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="testimony maincontent static"><div class="slider2">
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Portfolio</div><img src="slide1.png" height="200" width="200" /></div>
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Portfolio</div><img src="slide2.png" height="200" width="200" /></div>
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Portfolio</div><img src="slide3.png" height="200" width="200" /></div>
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Portfolio</div><img src="slide4.png" height="200" width="200" /></div>
</div></div>
</div>
```

***HTML OF OTHER DIV EFFECTED***

```
<div class="trigger large">
        <div tabindex="0" class="testimonywide maincontent staticlarge"><div class="slider">
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Special Offer</div><img src="slide1.png" height="200" width="400" /></div>
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Special Offer</div><img src="slide2.png" height="200" width="400" /></div>
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Special Offer</div><img src="slide3.png" height="200" width="400" /></div>
<div class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Special Offer</div><img src="slide4.png" height="200" width="400" /></div>
</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both square have border. just hide inside other div. you can give some margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `.trigger.large` has a width of 400px.
- `.staticlarge` (which is a child of the above) has a width of 400px plus 1px border. Its *outer* width is thus 402px.
- `.trigger` has `overflow: hidden` so it clips the overflowing 2px.

Solution is to remove hard-coded width of 400px on the child. If you must specify a width then specify one of these:

- 398px
- width: 100% + box-sizing: border-box
- width: calc(100% - 2px)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is width and height of that div is more because of which its getting **hidden**. Just look after them, you will be able to see the border.

To be more specific, reduce the height of `.sssprev, .sssnext` and `.staticlarge` elements. This will solve your problem. I have tested it on the link provided by you.

I tried with **150px** of width and I was able to see the border.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `.trigger` div and need to adjust the div accordingly .

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order border to the html just write

```
<div class="just_text" style="border-style: solid"><div class="caption-box">Special Offer</div><img src="slide4.png" height="200" width="400" /></div>
</div></div>
```

The style attribute gives border

```
style="border-style: solid"
```